# Is there a way to hide answers you don't want to see?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, images

Somewhere between the fine line between downvoting (which I did) and flagging (which I did not), we have stuff like this answer: [What are the similarities and differences between "irony" and "sarcasm"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26621/irony-vs-sarcasm/26622#26622)

As much as Oatmeal may amuse people, I really don't appreciate having to scroll through that many large images before finding other content. Is there a way to hide an answer?

Comment: My first thought was whether EL&U is violating copyright by simply hosting this entire comic. It might need to be deleted on those grounds; I am looking into it.

Comment: Based on what I read and feedback from other mods, I concluded that it is outside the bounds of fair use.  However, for those of us who can see deleted posts, it is still there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to hide an answer that you don't want to see.

Comment: the other way to deal with this is show a single frame (crop it) and link to the full comic. I've done that before as well.